# Double tap via VoiceOver on table cell not working on few cells

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

We have a tableview in a tableview cell and in that inner tableview, cells are populated dynamically(these cells hold a button within) and on tap on these cells they navigate to different screens and it works perfectly fine. But with VoiceOver turned on, navigating through the inner table cells via swipe gesture and double tap on the cells, VoiceOver just reads the button label again but doesn't perform the navigation.

And this applies only for specific cells but not for all. Surprising part is that, every cell used here is a tableview's dequeue reusable cell which behaves strange for few cells. And also this behaviour is reproducible only on certain iPhone devices while both VoiceOver and non VoiceOver flow works fine on other devices even when the iOS version is same between the two.

We have the cell accessibility element and also the button within it to true.